# Load programs using CreateProcess

Tags: delphi

Hi I have a function that makes CreateProcess load programs in this case try to upload a file with the path c: /test.mp3 c: /test.exe, I try to load my program console but never loaded programs

The code:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, ShellApi, Windows;

procedure cargar(ProgramName: String; Wait: Boolean);
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CreateOK: Boolean;
begin
  { fill with known state }
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ProgramName), nil, nil, False,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartInfo,
    ProcInfo);
  { check to see if successful }
  if CreateOK then
  begin
    // may or may not be needed. Usually wait for child processes
    if Wait then
      WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
  end
  else
  begin
    // ShowMessage('Unable to run '+ProgramName);
  end;

  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;

begin
  try

    cargar('c:/test.mp3', True);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MP3 file is not an executable application. If you'd like to open such file in a default, associated program, use `ShellExecute(Ex)`.

Comment: I 'm trying to do with CreateProcess because ShellExecute gives me problems when I try to use threads

Comment: As well as that, you are not passing writeable memory to the second parameter. You get away with that sometimes, particularly if you are calling CreateProcessA

Comment: "Problems when I try to use threads". That's rather imprecise. Of course, `CreateProcess` is pretty much hopeless at working out what program is associated with an extension. You should call `ShellExecute`, well `ShellExecuteEx`, and do it right. No reason for threads to be a problem.

Comment: `ShellExecute/Ex()` works just fine in a thread, though you might need to call `CoInitialize/Ex()` or `OleInitialize()` first, as it might need to invoke COM to handle the file.

Comment: ok , thanks for the help , then I use ShellExecute() and load multiple programs without problem or just need to use ShellExecuteEx() ?

Comment: @adsdsa, except extended parameters, the `ShellExecuteEx` function returns a handle to the started process on which you can wait just as you were waiting for the `ProcInfo.hProcess` in your code. That's what the `ShellExecute` function cannot. But neither `ShellExecute` nor `ShellExecuteEx` function lets you execute more than one file with a single call, if that's what you've asked in your comment. P.S. use @ char before the user's name (just like I did now) if you want that user be notified about a comment. We don't have to since you are the post owner and as such you are always notified.

Comment: Always use ShellExecuteEx because it reports errors in a sane manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement error checking (for example by calling RaiseLastOSError on failure), then Windows will tell you what is wrong: 'System Error.  Code: 193. %1 is not a valid Win32 application'.

You cannot use CreateProcess in order to launch an mp3 file directly. You'd have to launch a player application with the mp3 file as command line argument.